# Installation problem QGIS

Tags: qgis, dll

I do not manage to install QGIS on my windows 10 machine using the osgeo4w installer.

During the installation I get this message:
[image]

At the end of the installation I get this message:
[image]

And when I subsequently try to run QGIS, I receive this message: 
[image]

Similar issue can be found in various fora, but none of them provides a conluding answer or did help me to solve the problem.

Any propositions?

Comment: do you have an anti-virus/firewall software installed?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/240159/55203), I can't test this but a number of possible workarounds mentioned.

Comment: @Mapperz: Yes, I do have an anti-virus/firewall software installed (Symantec Endpoint protection). And it seems as it was indeed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed finally to install QGIS as explained above. 
However, I am not able to backtrace the solution.

What I did, however, where (at least) the following steps:

1. Remove the entire OSGeo4w directory
2. Install QGIS with the standalonw installer (This worked)(https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)
3. Uninstall QGIS again
4. Install QGIS with the OSGeo4w installer having the firewall/anti-virus disabled (This worked)
5. Uninstall QGIS and install it again having the firewall/anti-virus enables (This worked)

There might be other minor changes that have enabled the proper installation. However, I do not remember them or might not even be aware of them.

As pointed out by @AndreasMüller, the reason might be simply that the package had been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I think, the package was fixed in the meantime, so your first attempt should also work (again)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known packaging issue, see

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/unable-to-install-QGIS-with-OSGEO4W-on-windows-7-td5382341.html

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20112

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-fails-to-install-td5381875.html

As a workaround, I suggest to use an older standalone installer from http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/ until the matter is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [alternative installer by NextGIS](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) (but only QGIS 2.18 now). Newer versions of libraries and nice autoupdate tool. You can install it in separate folder - NextGIS QGIS does not affect OSGEO4W installation.

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I'm developer at NextGIS.