# Unable to open QGIS 3.2.3 Bonn

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have uninstalled and re-installed QGIS on my 64-bit Windows 10 Pro work computer.  I added the program into environmental variables and tried running it.  I received the following error message:
 [image: error message]

Could the issue be because I don't have rights to install as a user?

The files folder looks like this:

[image: file folder]

Comment: Did you get no entry in the start menu, or a new desktop folder?

Comment: The app appears in start menu. When launching an error message appears for "Could not load qgis_app.dll Windows Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application Help: Check C:\OSGEO4W64\bin\qgis-bin.env for correct environment paths". What should I have in environ variable? Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did with your environment varaibles in the first place, but that is not necessary. Ususally the program is invoked with `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis,bat`, and not with the exe file.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240159/qgis-2-18-the-program-cant-start-because-qgis-app-dll-is-missing-from-your-com  and https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18326

Answer (score 1):

So you have to go to folder where you installed qgis, than go into folder named "bin" and there u will find QGIS-bin.exe and from there start it.

I installed it on C drive so path is this C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\bin